# Apache - Convert underscores to dashes in headers

Tags: apache2.4, siteminder

In a project a had to run CA Webagent Siteminder which sends me legacy headers with underscores. Since Apache 2.4 underscores are deprecated and dropped silently.

I need a workaround via `mod_headers` which converts all underscores `_` to dashes `-` in the **request-header**.

**Before**

```
legacy_header_one
legacy_header_two
legacy_header_three
```

**After**

```
legacy-header-one
legacy-header-two
legacy-header-three
```

Comment: Are you trying to convert the header names or the header values or both?

Comment: I want to convert the `names`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. [Apache Bypass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/env.html#fixheader)

   ```
   # 
   # The following works around a client sending a broken Accept_Encoding
   # header.
   #
   SetEnvIfNoCase ^Accept.Encoding$ ^(.*)$ fix_accept_encoding=$1
   RequestHeader set Accept-Encoding %{fix_accept_encoding}e env=fix_accept_encoding
   ```
2. [Siteminder Bypass](https://support.ca.com/us/knowledge-base-articles.TEC1712544.html)

   ```
   #its not explicitly stated but im assuming this should be in your WebAgent.conf file
   LegacyVariables="NO"
   ```

EDIT:

I know this doesn't directly answer your question of converting from _ to - but it is an answer to help mitigate the Apache 2.4 vs. CA Siteminder header issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your virtualhost config:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase ^OAM.REMOTE.USER$ ^(.*)$ fix_accept_encoding=$1
RequestHeader set OAM-REMOTE-USER %{fix_accept_encoding}e env=fix_accept_encoding
```

If you are using mod_wsgi for Django or Flask, you will need to add:

`WSGIPassAuthorization On`

Comment: This only converts one specific header-variable to lowercase, doesn't it?